# Protractor test on input field with $asyncValidators fails

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, validation, protractor

When I try to test the validation of an input field having an async validator on it (`$asyncValidators`) it sporadically fails under protractor.

I am trying to send the keys and then checking for the css class `ng-valid/invalid` on the field.

```
element(by.name(inputFieldName)).sendKeys('Valid Input').then(function() {
    expect(element(by.name(inputFieldName)).getAttribute('class').then(function(classes) {return classes.split(' ');})).toContain('ng-valid');
});
```

I have the same test for an invalid input.

Sometimes the field unexpectedly has the opposite css class. Sometimes it even has neither of both, but contains `ng-pending`.

On the website of Angular I learned that `ng-pending` means

> ng-pending: any $asyncValidators are unfulfilled

How can I fix my test cases to wait for all async validators to fulfill?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is a method [`browser.waitForAngular()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.waitForAngular), you could try to put it after an action that supposed to do some job and before the next action, which requires first action to finish, sometimes in really helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with browser.waitForAngular()